# Find the Distributional Limit of the Sequence of Distributions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

> Find the distributional limit of the sequence of distributions
>
> $$F_n=n\delta_{-\frac{1}{n}}-n\delta_{\frac{1}{n}}$$
>
> Hint: $F_n$ is the distributional derivative of some function

So far I've tried kind of working backwards towards the definition of the distributional derivative to make use of the hint:

$$F_n=n\delta_{-\frac{1}{n}}-n\delta_{\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$F_n=<n\delta_{-\frac{1}{n}},\phi>-<n\delta_{\frac{1}{n}},\phi>$$
$$n\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}\phi'(x) \ dx$$
$$-\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\phi'(x) \ dx$$
$$-<f,\phi'> \ = \ <f',\phi>$$
where
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-n  & \text{$-\frac{1}{n}\le x\le\frac{1}{n}$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here and how following this hint got me closer to the answer.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take some test function $\phi$, then

$$\langle F_n, \phi\rangle = \int n\big(\delta(x+\tfrac 1n) - \delta(x-\tfrac 1n)\big)\phi(x) d x = n\big(\phi(-\tfrac 1n)-\phi(+\tfrac 1n)\big)
\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} -2\phi'(0) $$

So the limit distribution $F$ is the linear functional $F(\phi) = -2\phi'(0)$. In particular $F=2\delta'$.

Comment: how did you get to $-2\phi'(0)$ for when $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: @nickoba https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative Note that $\phi$ is smooth by assumption.

Comment: the -2 is still throwing me off, could u care to explain that part of it? because wouln't it be $\infty$ instead of -2?

Comment: @nickoba It is $-2\phi'(0)$ but there was a small sign mistake, which I fixed now. We have $\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2 h} = f'(x)$. Substitute $x=0$, $h=1/n$ and $f=\phi$.